# bitcoin-cli createwallet electrumpersonal server true

Tags: electrum

I'm a noob following instructions to setup Electrum Personal Server on Linux.

I came to this instruction and I'm stuck.

Got an warning. What is this?

```
{
  "name": "electrumpersonalserver",
  "warning": ""
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no warning there.

The `createwallet` command will always return a JSON object containing the name of the wallet created, and a warning string. If there was a warning during wallet creation, that warning string would contain text. But it is just an empty string so there is no warning.